# decoded Hbase row using curl command

Tags: shell, curl, base64, hbase

I have a curl command to fetch a row from hbase consumption view/table. This curl command always returns me base64 encoded data. Is there a shorthand of decoding the data directly or will I need to write some script (python) to get it decoded?

Comment: did you try to add `"Accept: application/json"` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. its returning a json object, but keys and values inside this json is base64 encoded.

Comment: I guess you will need to do a script, but it can be a bash script with the base64 command... maybe someone knows a better way sorry